# Are there any non-trivial automorphisms on $(\mathbb{N}, \times)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, logic

Obviously the identity is an automorphism. But any time other bijection I can think of does not preserve multiplication. Is the identity the only automorphism on $(\mathbb{N}, \times)$?

Comment: Note that any automorphism is completely determined by its values on primes. Consider something like $\phi(2)=3, \phi(3)=2$ and identity on other primes.

Comment: Did you try using the unique factorization into prime factors and then exchange primes?

Comment: So I initially thought of functions that were identity everywhere but switched two primes up. So $\phi(n) = n$ for all $n \neq 2,3$. And then $\phi(2) = 3$ and $\phi(3) = 2$. But this obviously doesn't work. Take $n=10$. Then $\phi(2 \times 5) = 10$. But $\phi(2) \times \phi(5) = 3 \times 5 = 15$.

Comment: Oh, I think I realize where I went wrong. I need $\phi(n) = \phi(p_1) .... \phi(p_n)$ where each $p_i$ is the prime factorization of $n$.

Comment: For the composite number $n$ we define $\phi(n)$ by the product of $\phi(p_i)$ for each $p_i$ in the prime factorization of $n$.

Answer (score 2):

Pick any permutation $f\colon \Bbb P\to\Bbb P$ of the set $\Bbb P$ of all primes and define
$$\phi(\prod_i p_i^{a_i}):=\prod_i f(p_i)^{a_i}. $$